# Atualizar o valor de uma variavel pro resultado da soma dela com +1

Tags: javascript, html, variáveis

Eu tenho uma variável que é um número, quero atualizar o valor dela quando o botão é clicado... Porém quero atualizar o valor com somas, por exemplo: o valor da variável é 0. Mas quando o botão é clicado o valor atualiza pro resultado do valor atual (0) somado por 1 (0+1)
Ou seja,
A variável vai atualizar o valor pra 1. E por ai vai.

**EXEMPLO CÓDIGO HTML:**

O código abaixo faz um botão que diz "crescer":

`<input type="button" value="crescer" onclick="buttonclick();" />`

Agora o **JAVASCRIPT:**

````
var idade = 0
   
function buttonclick() {
    var eunaosei = "ai era pra estar a solução pra mudar o valor pra soma 0+1, 1+1 e por ai vai.."
}

document.write('Idade:');
document.write(idade);```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para incrementar um valor em JavaScript existem quatro formas. A mais comum e simples de todas é utilizando o operador `++` que irá somar `+1` ao valor da variável. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var valor = 2;
valor++;

console.log(valor);  // Resultado: 3
```

A segunda forma é também utilizando o operador `++`, porém aqui você deve utilizá-lo antes da variável. A diferença dessa forma para a primeira é que na primeira forma o valor é incrementado somente depois do mesmo ter sido usado. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
var valor = 2;
console.log(valor++); // Imprime 2 porque o incremento vem depois.
console.log(++valor); // Imprime 4 porque o incremento vem antes.
```

A terceira forma é utilizando o operador `+=` que irá incrementar um valor X à variável. Nessa forma você mesmo especifica o valor que será somado, sendo bem diferente da primeira forma onde o valor somado é `1` obrigatoriamente.

```js
var valor = 2;
valor += 5;

console.log(valor);  // Resultado: 7
```

A última forma é atribuindo à variável o seu próprio valor somado a um outro valor que desejar, utilizando o operador de soma.

```js
var valor = 3;
valor = valor + 1;

console.log(valor);  // Resultado: 4
```

Como você viu no exemplo acima, tanto a terceira quanto a quarta forma são equivalentes. Sendo assim, se quiser deixar seu código menor e mais bonito, utilize a terceira forma.

Veja agora este último exemplo que talvez seja o que deseja:

```js
let value = 0;

function incrementar() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = `Value: ${++value}`;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="incrementar();" value="Incrementar"/>
<div id="display" style="padding-top: 15px;">Value: 0</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa [incrementar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) a sua variável. Para isso, existem algumas formas diferentes:

```js
var n = 0;
function crescer(){
  n++;
}
crescer();
console.log(n); // mostra o valor de n
```

```js
var n = 0;
function crescer(){
  n += 1;
}
crescer();
console.log(n); // mostra o valor de n
```

Ou então:

```js
var n = 0;
function crescer(){
  n = n + 1;
}
crescer();
console.log(n); // mostra o valor de n
```